# CakePHP Pagination won't allow public $paginate variable to change depending on conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

I'm using CakePHP v2.4.1, and I'm trying to have two separate models be paginated on the same page, through the same controller action (index)

I want to have a NewsPost paginated on a single page, and the EventPost also paginated separately on the same page.  Is this bad practice, or is it possible to set conditions to change the $this->paginate variable to paginate properly depending on which model it is on?

My Controller looks like this:

```
public $uses = array(
    'NewsPost',
    'NewsPostComment',
    'EventPost',
    'EventPostComment'
);

public $paginate = array(
'limit' => 9,
'order' => array(
    'NewsPost.created' => 'desc'
), 
'recursive' => 1,
);

public function index() {       

  $this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 1,
    'order' => array(
        'EventPost.created' => 'desc'
    ), 
    'recursive' => 1,
  ); 

$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
$newsPosts = $this->paginate('NewsPost');

$eventPosts = $this->EventPost->find('all');
$this->set(array('newsPosts' => $newsPosts, 'eventPosts' => $eventPosts));
```

The built-in cake paginator does not seem to allow for the options of paginating separate models, or am I wrong?

Here is the view for pagination:

```
<?php 
$params = $this->Paginator->params();
if ($params['count'] > 0): ?>
<div class="pagination-totals pull-left">
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => __('{:start} to {:end} of {:count}'))) ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
    'class' => 'pull-right',
    'prev'     => '<',
    'next'     => '>',
)); 
?>
```

The problem is, when I choose page two for the NewsPost, it switches to page two for the EventPost, so how can I differentiate between both separate models on the same page using CakePHP pagination?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have just one params named page in your page so the result in normal.

You have to handle this with ajax request and separated actions